# How can I infer the joint distribution of an observed and a latent variable?

Tags: inference, joint-distribution, latent-variable

I have a dataset of school children with three features:

- Age $x$ of the student answering the survey
- Year group $a$ of the student answering the survey
- Year group $b$ of the best friend of the student answering the survey

How can I infer the joint distribution $P\left(xy\right)$ of the age of each student $x$ and the age of their best friend $y$? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

## An attempt

I can infer the age distribution of students in each year group (using a KDE, for example). However, that only gives me access to the conditional distribution $P\left(y|b\right)$ of the age $y$ of the best friend given their year group $b$, not $P\left(xy\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

I will make use of two assumptions:

1. The conditional distribution of Age given Group is the same as the conditional distribution of BFAge given BFGroup
2. The dependence of BFAge on Age is mediated entirely by BFGroup.  In symbols, 
   $P(\text{BFAge}=b|\text{Age}=a,\text{BFGroup}=b)=P(\text{BFAge}=b|\text{BFGroup}=b)$

The first assumption you have already basically made in your question when you claimed that you could estimate the conditional distribution of BFAge given BFGroup.  Since you can't see BFAge, what you must be thinking is that you can estimate this conditional distribution by the conditional distribution of Age given Group, which you can estimate from the data you have.

The second assumption is strong.  It says that everything there is to know about the conditional distribution of BFAge given Age is conveyed by group membership.  That, for example, a student who is old for his group will not systematically have a best friend who is old for the best friend's group.  But, obviously, you have to make some strong assumption here, because assumptions and data are substitutes and you have no data on BFAge.

Anyway, first you estimate the conditional distribution of BFAge given Age like this:
\begin{align}
P(&\text{BFAge}=b|\text{Age}=a) \\
  &=\sum_g P(\text{BFAge}=b|\text{Age}=a,\text{BFGroup}=g) 
             P(\text{BFGroup}=g|\text{Age}=a)\\
  &=\sum_g P(\text{BFAge}=b|\text{BFGroup}=g)P(\text{BFGroup}=g|\text{Age}=a)\\
  &=\sum_g P(\text{Age}=b|\text{Group}=g)P(\text{BFGroup}=g|\text{Age}=a)
\end{align}
Everything in the last line you can estimate with your data.  Going from the second to the third line requires assumption 2 above.  Going from the third to the last line requires assumption 1 above.

Once you have $P(\text{BFAge}=b|\text{Age}=a)$, you just integrate to get what you want:
\begin{align}
P(\text{BFAge}=b,\text{Age}=a) = \sum_a P(\text{BFAge}=b|\text{Age}=a)P(\text{Age}=a)
\end{align}